How to specify the ordering of subpages in Wagtail admin
In Wagtail, consider the following page types:
class WorkshopPage(Page):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
    WorkshopCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
)

class WorkshopIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    subpage_types = ["WorkshopPage"]

In the wagtail admin, I need to order the subpages of WorkshopIndexPage by their category__name.
Since in the docs it says that setting ordering in a WorkshopPage Meta class will not work (it does not), I have tried the solution proposed here. However, when I do this inside my WorkshopIndexPage:
    def get_children(self):
        qs = WorkshopPage.objects.order_by("category__name")
        return qs

I get an error: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.
This seems like a simple use case but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently there is no straight way to sort sub-pages in wagtail.
You have two options:

Use inline models which is inline field for manytomany relationships.
Add your own field for ordering sub-pages

Here is a quick list of changes to implement 2nd method:

add a field to the page model for subpages to store an integer for sorting it's instances:

display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


add meta class to the same model to indicate the field used for default ordering:

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["display_order"]


add this field to content_panels to enable it in edit page.
optional - implement the sort in front-end by overriding context:

def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    context['subpages'] = self.get_children().live().order_by('display_order')
    return context


Your code will probably look like this:
class WorkshopPage(Page):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
    WorkshopCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
)
    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("display_order"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["display_order"]


class WorkshopIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    subpage_types = ["WorkshopPage"]

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['workshop_pages'] = self.get_children().live().order_by('display_order')
        return context



Try this code in wagtail_hooks.py:
@hooks.register('construct_explorer_page_queryset')
def apply_default_order_to_workshop_index_page(parent_page, pages, request):

    if parent_page.slug == 'workshops' and 'ordering' not in request.GET:
        pages = WorkshopPage.objects.child_of(parent_page).order_by('category__name')
    
    return pages

See this and this for more information.
